# Entropy before and after sampling an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Suppose I have N ideal gas particles of unknown types, but they have the same mass. I then sample a *negligible* number of particles and conclude I have actually have 3 different colors of particles. That is, my detector measures the color of a random sample of particles (and nothing else) and by chernoff bound from a small sample size I conclude (with high probability) that I have some mixture $ p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3} = 1 $ so that I have $ p_{1} N $ red particles, $ p_{2} N $ blue particles, and $ p_{3} N $ green particles. Then from Sackur-Tetrode:
$$ S_{ \text{before sampling} } = k \, N \left( ln \left[ \frac{V}{N} \left( \frac{ 4 \pi m }{ 3 h^{2} } \frac{U}{N} \right)^{3/2} \right] + \frac{5}{2} \right) $$

$$ S_{ \text{after sampling} } = \sum_{i=1}^{3} p_{i} k \, N \left( ln \left[ \frac{V}{p_{i} N} \left( \frac{ 4 \pi m }{ 3 h^{2} } \frac{U}{ p_{i} N} \right)^{3/2} \right] + \frac{5}{2} \right) = S_{ \text{before sampling} } - \frac{5}{2} k \, N \left( \sum_{i=1}^{3} p_{i} ln \left( p_{i} \right) \right) $$

So recognizing some feature of my particles, regardless of how relevant to any of the physical properties of the particles, seems to change the entropy. If entropy has physical consequences, shouldn't there be a way to know if to regard or disregard properties of relevance or irrelevance in a system? Otherwise it would seem that inconsequential features may change my physical understanding.

Comment: Precisely what are the states of the system before and after?

Comment: before and after I "discover" the color-ness of the particles.

Comment: Why not an expression like this: 
$$ S ( \vec{N}, \vec{V}, \vec{U} ) = S_{Sackur-Tetrode} + \frac{5}{2} k \, N \left( \sum_{i}^{ \dim{N} } \frac{ N_{i} }{ N } \ln \left( \frac{ N_{i} }{ N } \right)  + \ln \left( \frac{ V_{i} }{ V } \right)  + \ln \left( \frac{ U_{i} }{ U } \right)  \right) $$
which would be invariant to this sort of behavior it seems to me.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315104/does-entropy-depend-on-the-observer

Comment: Is it necessarily the case that we cannot find entropy expressions that are invariant under irrelevant additional information? Is it contradictory to the axioms of entropy that $ S(N_{1}+N_{2}, V, U) = S(N_{1}, V, U) + S(N_{2}, V, U) $, or do we just need to find clever expressions to capture this?