# Entropy and observers

Tags: cosmology, entropy, universe, observers

Struggling to understand the stance Bousso takes in his paper, The Entropic Landscape,

https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1155

Is he saying that because only by observing an increase in available state we can say entropy increases? Like in Ruben Verresen's answer to [Does entropy depend on the observer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315104/)